# Get the matching index of a value in a list

Tags: c#, list

So I've got the following code:

```
string matchingName = "Bob";
List<string> names = GetAllNames();
if (names.Contains(matchingName))
    // Get the index/position in the list of names where Bob exists
```

Is it possible to do this with a couple of lines of code, rather than iterating through the list to get the index or position?

Comment: Something like `names.IndexOf(matchingName)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple matching instances and want to get all the indices you can use this:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, names.Count).Where(i => names[i] == matchingName);
```

If it is just one index you want, then this will work:

```
int result = names.IndexOf(matchingName);
```

If there is no matching instance in `names`, the former solution will yield an empty enumeration, while the latter will give -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = names.IndexOf(matchingName);
if (index != -1)
{
     // do something with index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look for a **single** match, then [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx) will suit your purposes.

If you want to look for **multiple** matches, consider:

```
var names = new List<string> {"Bob", "Sally", "Hello", "Bob"};

var bobIndexes = names.Select((value, index) => new {value, index})
    .Where(z => z.value == "Bob")
    .Select(z => z.index);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", bobIndexes)); // this outputs 0,3
```

The use of `(value, index)` within [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) gives you access to both the element **and** its index.